# How to use v-item-group when using vue.components - Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I'm trying to create a group of selectable items using `Vuetify`.
Nevertheless, it is not working because inside the template I'm using a Vue.component called fm-card.

When you use a `Vue.component` you have to use `@click.native` instead of `@click`.

```html
<v-item-group active-class="primary">
  <v-container>
    <v-row justify="center">
      <v-col
        class="fm-card-container"
        cols="2"
        v-for="item in items"
        v-bind:key="item.id"
      >
        <v-item v-slot="{ active, toggle }">
          <fm-card
            @click.native="toggle;"
            class="fm-card d-flex align-center"
            :title="item.name"
            :image="productImage(item.image)"
            :imageHeight="95"
            dark
            height="200"
            :color="active ? 'primary' : ''"
          >
            {{`hola soy el ${toggle}`}}
            <v-scroll-y-transition>
              <div v-if="active" class="text-h2 flex-grow-1 text-center">
                Active
              </div>
            </v-scroll-y-transition>
          </fm-card>
        </v-item>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</v-item-group>
```

I have tried to use @click and @click.native but it seems that nothing is happening

Comment: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/item-groups/

Answer (score 0):

First of all why don't you put your `<fm-card>` as an "real" component and reference it in your parent and pass all of your `values` you are using in there with it?

Like this

```
<fm-card :value1="value1" :value2="value2"/>
```

than you can put your complete code in this component - it's making your code much more clearer.

And than I think you don't need to use `@click.native` any more... `@click` should be enough, but than check that you have a semicolon after your `toggle;` - you have to delete this!

Than you can go to your methods and work with your click event like this:

```
methods: {
  toggle() {
    //your code in here
  }
}
```

Hopefully this helps you out! Pls let me know!